# Cannot get "_set" from model using "self" in foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to get the related objects using `_set` in Django. I want to get all objects which are referring to the parent object.

My model:

```
class MessageBoard(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    message = models.TextField()
    person = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", default=None, null=True)
```

But when I try to get the set of an object I get an error.

```
>>> msg = MessageBoard.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> msgs = msg.parent_set.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MessageBoard' object has no attribute 'parent_set'
```

If I do

```
>>> MessageBoard.objects.filter(parent=1)
```

It returns the objects as I want. I need to use `_set` (or another way which achieves the same result), because I want to use inside django templates.

Comment: The default back reference is not named by the field, but by the model. It should be `messageboard_set`. Since the name is confusing, I advise to set the `related_name` on the `ForeignKey`.

Comment: You are right. Can you post as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks, my friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default back reference is not named by the field, but by the model. It should be `messageboard_set`.

Since the name is confusing, I advise to set the `related_name` on the `ForeignKey`.